# Imagemagick parallel conversion

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I want to get screenshot of each page of a `pdf` into `jpg`. To do this I am using `ImageMagick`'s `convert` command in command line.

I have to achieve the following -

1. Get screenshots of each page of the pdf file.
2. resize the screenshot into 3 different sizes (small, med and preview).
3. store the different sizes in different folders (small, med and preview).

I am using the following command which works, however, it is slow. How can I improve its execution time or execute the commands parallely.

```
convert -density 400 -quality 100 /input/test.pdf -resize 170x117> -scene 1 /small/test_%d_small.jpg & convert -density 400 -quality 100 /input/test.pdf -resize 230x160> -scene 1 /med/test_%d_med.jpg & convert -density 400 -quality 100 /input/test.pdf -resize 1310x650> -scene 1 /preview/test_%d_preview.jpg
```

**Splitting the command for readability**

```
convert -density 400 -quality 100 /input/test.pdf -resize 170x117> -scene 1 /small/test_%d_small.jpg

convert -density 400 -quality 100 /input/test.pdf -resize 230x160> -scene 1 /med/test_%d_med.jpg 

convert -density 400 -quality 100 /input/test.pdf -resize 1310x650> -scene 1 /preview/test_%d_preview.jpg
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

I see you have long, multi-page documents and while my original answer is good for making multiple sizes of a single page quickly, it doesn't address doing pages in parallel. So, here is a way of doing it using GNU Parallel which is available for free for OS X (using `homebrew`), installed on most Linux distros and also available for Windows - if you really must.

The code looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob
shopt -s nocaseglob

doPage(){
   # Expecting filename as first parameter and page number as second
   # echo DEBUG: File: $1 Page: $2
   noexten=${1%%.*}
   convert -density 400 -quality 100 "$1[$2]"     \
      -resize 1310x650 -write "${noexten}-p-$2-large.jpg" \
      -resize 230x160  -write "${noexten}-p-$2-med.jpg"   \
      -resize 170x117  "${noexten}-p-$2-small.jpg"
}

export -f doPage

# First, get list of all PDF documents
for d in *.pdf; do
   # Now get number of pages in this document - "pdfinfo" is probably quicker
   p=$(identify "$d" | wc -l)
   for ((i=0;i<$p;i++));do
      echo $d:$i
   done
done | parallel --eta --colsep ':' doPage {1} {2}
```

If you want to see how it works, remove the `| parallel ....` from the last line and you will see that the preceding loop just echoes a list of filenames and a counter for the page number into GNU Parallel. It will then run one process per CPU core, unless you specify `-j 8` if you want say 8 processes to run in parallel. Remove the `--eta` if you don't want any updates on when the command is likely to finish.

In the comment I allude to `pdfinfo` being faster than `identify`, if you have that available (it's part of the `poppler` package under `homebrew` on OS X), then you can use this to get the number of pages in a PDF:

```
pdfinfo SomeDocument.pdf | awk '/^Pages:/ {print $2}'
```

**Original Answer**

Something along these lines so you only read it in once and then generate successively smaller images from the largest one:

```
convert -density 400 -quality 100 x.pdf \
   -resize 1310x650 -write large.jpg    \
   -resize 230x160  -write medium.jpg   \
   -resize 170x117  small.jpg
```

Unless you mean you have, say, a 50 page PDF, and you want to do all 50 pages in parallel. If you do, say so, and I'll show you that using GNU Parallel when I get up in 10 hours...

Comment: Thank you @Mark. The pdf's I have do have many pages, 50 too. I'll look forward for your help. Also, the image filename should have the "page number" starting from 1.