# Convert PDF to PNG very very fast like Verisign/Docusign

Tags: php, pdf

I been using PDF to PNG conversions and tried both ImageMagick and also Ghostscript.

I have a 36 page document that is split into individual PDFs. The FASTEST I've gotten this conversion down for all 36 pages on an i7 machine running Linux with 8 GB of RAM is around 20 seconds.

I see VeriSign/DocuSign and even of course Adobe EchoSign able to convert all of these files to be "previewed" in under 10 seconds (sometimes around like 5 seconds).

Is there something I'm missing?  Is it literally just all about the machine itself?

This is the fastest i've gotten them to convert using Ghostscript and this command:

```
gs -q -dQUIET -qNODISPLAY -dNumRenderingThreads=4 -dNOPAUSE \
   -sDEVICE=jpeg -sOutputFile=$exportPathCleaned -dJPEGQ=90 \
   -r100 -q $pdf -c quit
```

Is it just impossible to hit their speeds?
***EDIT***   PHP/Java platforms is what I'm targeting

***EDIT 2 for clarification*** - Wanting to be able to do this to develop a similar system to VeriSign/DocuSign etc so that divs and other items can be placed on the output view.  To my knowledge you can't do this with a direct PDF which is why they convert everything to images.

Comment: have you tried MuPDF?

Comment: Can you provide (a link to) your sample PDF?

Comment: Also, which versions of Ghostscript and ImageMagick did you test with?

Comment: I can't technically link the sample PDF because its a secure document with personal information.  I can say that its 36 pages of pure text.  Here is one that has text and images and of course is much much longer to convert http://classidex.com/Test/EVS.pdf

I'm running php 5.4 thats all i know

Comment: @Dagon I can't find any information on MuPDF to be used with PHP/Java.  If you can point me into that direction I would be open to trying it out.  I only see it talk about Android integration

Comment: @eqiz You could use pdftk to flatten the pdf and preview it instead of changing it to a png.

Comment: @Daniel if you just previewing it as a PDF then how would you do drag & drop div's ontop of it like the sites listed above for signatures etc?  You can't do that on a PDF to my knowledge.

Comment: @eqiz You can fill an interactive pdf with pdftk all you have to do is install the pdftk server on your local machine and specifying the fields of the pdf. If that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @Daniel We don't want to mess with just an interactive PDF.  We want the ability to create an interactive fill on the fly with ability for digital signatures and also creating and manipulating fields directly on screen.  If you check out what VeriSign/DocuSign are I think you would have a better understanding what I mean

Comment: Using fonts other than the base fonts can increase the time it takes to convert the documents. I am not sure you can "fix" what you want. I have sent documents to DocuSign that took a long time to render also. Perhaps a solution where you render/show page one and continue the rest in the background?

Comment: If you will run the conversion on 1 server it will go over all of the pages and convert them one by one. However - if (for example) you will have 36 servers, and each will convert 1 page, your execution time will decrease dramatically. Try to check how much time it will take to convert only 1 page (of the 36-pages pdf), check what is the most time-consumer page in that pdf, distribute your job over several machines (each will convert a different page) and the only thing you need is to join the final PNG's, which i guess is a much less cpu-consuming job.

Comment: We have a very similar product used for designing documents (VisualXSL from RenderX). We licensed verypdf's convertor (for Windows). I just tested a 192 page pdf with mostly text and some images and it took 35 seconds for splitting all 192 pages, creating an image for each one and importing them into that application on a laptop.

Comment: You could check out, and maybe vote for ;-) my answer here about doing pages in parallel... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31105241/imagemagick-parallel-conversion/31105564#31105564

Comment: @Mark Setchell the problem is this method can be done with GS as well with just setting a start and finish page using %d also, how the same result comes out with it taking the same time.  Since theres no true "multi-threading" without forking, I haven't found a better way of doing it.  On that note, I have found even with forking using cURL, it still is just as slow because GS and ImageMagic themselves run in a "queue" type of setup.  So if i cURL 3 different page requests, the first always gets done first, then the 2nd is done, then the 3rd.  They aren't all done "simultaneously"

Comment: If you cannot provide (a link to the) sample PDF *"because its a secure document with personal information"*, and if this question is important to you, then you surely can create a dummy PDF which matches your original one in structure and content type? (Also, you didn't respond to my question about the GS and IM versions you were testing with...)

Comment: @KurtPfeifle I did include an example pdf....  i'll link it again classidex.com/Test/EVS.pdf  not sure how you missed that lol I also mentioned i'm running PHP 5.4, thats all I know.  I don't know what version of GS or IM is being used.  I haven't found a way to determine that.

Comment: Ghostscript version is reported by `gs -version`. ImageMagick version is reported by `convert -version`. To be sure (in case you have multiple installations) run these commands from within PHP (via `exec`).

Answer (score 3):

I used this command, on a 4 year old MacBook Pro with 4 GByte of RAM, processing your linked sample PDF:

```
$> time gs -q -sDEVICE=jpeg -o evs-%02d.jpg -dJPEGQ=90 -r100 EVS.pdf
```

which returns 11 JPEGs, with this timing information:

```
real  0m1.011s
user  0m1.063s
sys   0m0.091s
```

That is: `~1 sec` for 11 pages.

I do not see any performance problem with your sample PDF. However, your PDF is not completely kosher, as this warning message from Ghostscript indicates:

```
**** Warning: can't process font stream, loading font by the name.

**** This file had errors that were repaired or ignored.
**** The file was produced by: 
**** >>>> Acrobat Distiller 9.5.5 (Windows) <<<<
**** Please notify the author of the software that produced this
**** file that it does not conform to Adobe's published PDF
**** specification.
```

The file contains 231 images or stencils.

Further, it doesn't have embedded (all) the fonts it uses:

```
$> pdffonts Documents/pdfs/EVS.pdf

name                      type          encoding     emb sub uni object ID
------------------------- ------------- ------------ --- --- --- ---------
TimesNewRomanPSMT         TrueType      WinAnsi      no  no  no     636  0
TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT    TrueType      WinAnsi      no  no  no     638  0
Arial-Black               TrueType      WinAnsi      no  no  no     335  0
EPBFLF+Cambria            CID TrueType  Identity-H   yes yes yes    332  0
Helvetica                 Type 1        Custom       no  no  no     511  0
ArialMT                   TrueType      WinAnsi      no  no  no     476  0
FAMLHA+Wingdings-Regular  CID TrueType  Identity-H   yes yes yes    496  0
TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT  TrueType      WinAnsi      no  no  no     495  0
```

If these fonts were embedded, Ghostscript would not have to...

1. ...search for an appropriate substitute font,
2. ...load that substitute font from the harddisk,
3. ...apply the substitute font when rendering to JPEG output.

The processing into JPEGs will be faster ***even though the PDF with the fonts embedded will be bigger!***

I verified my last assertion by embedding the fonts into your sample PDF and running the above command again:

```
$> time gs -q -sDEVICE=jpeg -o evs-%02d.jpg -dJPEGQ=90 -r100 EVS-emb.pdf

 real  0m0.731s
 user  0m0.642s
 sys   0m0.072s
```

Answer (score 0):

i use ubuntu and this command converted all pdf to images\png

```
for f in *.pdf; do convert -quality 100 $f ${f%%.*}.jpg; done
```